# SQL Server : how to select maximum value from third column to each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select the maximum value of a related table for each row and order by this.

Please take the example below with tables Users, Items and Purchases. The table Purchases identify the Items each user purchased.

Now I need to get the list of Users ordered by the highest value purchased (and in case of tie by the lowest Purchase Date).

What is the best way to do this query?

USERS:

```
CREATE TABLE [Users]
(
    [UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
            WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                  IGNORE_DUP_KEY= OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserID], [userName], [Country])
 VALUES
       (1, 'John', 'France'), (2, 'Mary', 'Germany'), (3, 'Paco', 'Spain'),
       (4, 'Fran', 'Italy'), (5, 'Smith', 'USA'), (6, 'Anna', 'Italy'),
       (7, 'Cris', 'Belgium')


UserID | UserName | Country
-------+----------+-------------
   1   | John     | France
   2   | Mary     | Germany
   3   | Paco     | Spain
   4   | Fran     | Italy
   5   | Smith    | USA
   6   | Anna     | Italy
   7   | Cris     | Belgium
```

ITEMS:

```
CREATE TABLE [Items]
(
    [ItemID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ItemName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ItemID] ASC)
            WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [Items] ([ItemID], [ItemName], [Value])
VALUES
       (1, 'Keyboard', 10), (2, 'Mouse', 5),
       (3, 'Display', 40), (4, 'Laptop', 50), (5, 'Tablet', 50)


ItemID | ItemName | Value
-------+----------+-----  
   1   | Keyboard |  10
   2   | Mouse    |   5
   3   | Display  |  40
   4   | Laptop   |  50
   5   | Tablet   |  50
```

PURCHASES:

```
CREATE TABLE [Purchases]
(
    [UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ItemID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [PurchaseDate] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Purchases] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC, [ItemID] ASC, [PurchaseDate] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [Purchases] ([UserID], [ItemID], [PurchaseDate])
VALUES (3, 4, '2019-01-05'), (1, 2, '2019-02-07'), (3, 5, '2019-01-03'),
       (2, 5, '2019-01-02'), (4, 4, '2019-01-01'), (5, 1, '2019-03-05'),
       (6, 2, '2019-02-15'), (7, 1, '2019-01-01'), (5, 3, '2019-01-07')


UserID | ItemID | PurchaseDate
-------+--------+--------------
   3   |   4    | 2019-01-05
   1   |   2    | 2019-02-07
   3   |   5    | 2019-01-03
   2   |   5    | 2019-01-02
   4   |   4    | 2019-01-01
   5   |   1    | 2019-03-05
   6   |   2    | 2019-02-15
   7   |   1    | 2019-01-01
   5   |   3    | 2019-01-07
```

This is the query result that I  need:

```
UserName | ItemName | Value | PurchaseDate
---------+----------+-------+------------- 
Fran     | Laptop   |   50  | 2019-01-01  
Mary     | Tablet   |   50  | 2019-01-02  
Paco     | Tablet   |   50  | 2019-01-03  
Smith    | Display  |   40  | 2019-01-07  
Cris     | Keyboard |   10  | 2019-01-01  
John     | Mouse    |    5  | 2019-02-07  
Anna     | Mouse    |    5  | 2019-02-15
```

and this is the code I'm trying for now:

```
SELECT
    T1.UserName, T1.ItemName, T1.Value, T1.PurchaseDate 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY U.UserName ORDER BY I.value DESC, P.PurchaseDate ASC) AS rn, 
         P.PurchaseDate, U.UserName, I.value, I.ItemName 
     FROM 
         Purchases P
     INNER JOIN 
         Items I ON P.ItemID = I.ItemID 
     INNER JOIN 
         Users U ON P.UserID = U.UserID) T1
WHERE
    T1.rn = 1
ORDER BY 
    Value DESC, PurchaseDate ASC
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried

Comment: show what I tried point us to a path that can be the wrong one...that's why I asked the best way.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: all added for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function `FIRST_VALUE` to retrieve the ItemId for the purchase with the highest value. Then join those values back on the Purchases table to get the date (I took the latest one in case of duplicates).

```
;WITH userPurchase AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT u.userId, FIRST_VALUE(p.ItemId) OVER (PARTITION BY u.UserId ORDER BY i.Value DESC) as ItemId
    FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Purchases p
        ON u.UserId = p.UserId
    INNER JOIN Items i
        on p.ItemId = i.ItemId

)
,TopPurchases AS
(
    SELECT p.UserId, p.ItemId, MAX(p.PurchaseDate) as PurchaseDate
    FROM userPurchase u
    INNER JOIN Purchases p
        ON u.userId = p.UserId AND u.ItemId = p.ItemId
        GROUP BY p.UserId, p.ItemId
)
SELECT u.UserName, i.ItemName, i.Value , t.PurchaseDate
FROM TopPurchases t
INNER JOIN Users u 
    ON u.userId = t.userId
INNER JOIN Items i
    ON i.ItemId = t.ItemId
ORDER BY i.Value DESC, t.PurchaseDate
```